# What can cause Akka's Scheduler to execute scheduled tasks before the scheduled time?

Tags: scala, akka, scheduled-tasks, future

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when using Akka's scheduler. My code looks roughly like this:

```
    val s = ActorSystem("scheduler")

    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    def doSomething(): Future[Unit] = {
      val now = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
      println(s"${now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)}:${now.get(Calendar.SECOND)}:${now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)}" )

      // Do many things that include an http request using "dispatch" and manipulation of the response and saving it in a file.
    }

    val futures: Seq[Future[Unit]] = for (i <- 1 to 500) yield {
      println(s"$i : ${i*600}")
      // AlphaVantage recommends 100 API calls per minute
      akka.pattern.after(i * 600 milliseconds, s.scheduler) { doSomething() }
    }
    Future.sequence(futures).onComplete(_ => s.terminate())
```

When I execute my code, `doSomething` is initially called repeatedly with 600 milliseconds between successive calls, as expected. However, after a while, all remaining scheduled calls are suddenly executed simultaneously.

I suspect that something inside my `doSomething` might be interfering with the scheduling, but I don't know what. My `doSomething` just does an http request using dispatch and manipulates the result, and does not interact directly with akka or the scheduler in any way. So, my question is:

What can cause the Scheduler's schedule to fail and suddenly trigger the immediate execution of all remaining scheduled tasks?

(PS: I tried to simplify my `doSomething` to post a minimal *non-working* example here, but my simplifications resulted in *working* examples.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. As soon as one of the futures fail, the line

```
Future.sequence(futures).onComplete(_ => s.terminate())
```

will terminate the actor system, and all remaining scheduled tasks will be called.